# Let's not have sponsored content in the blog

Tags: discussion, feature-request, blog

Stack Overflow recently published [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/12/practical-ways-to-write-better-javascript/) blog post about "JavaScript Best Practices" and send quite a bit of traffic towards it through the regular blog link on the website.

This smells a lot like *paid marketing content* for a company. The author there has an interest to sell stuff to developers but the article is presented as if they are writing it out of the goodness of their hearts.

Stack Overflow is trusted by developers to not be "Experts Exchange" and to be a place where content is evaluated on merit and it is relatively transparent.

I would like to ask that:

- When you publish a third party technical article - please disclose any business relationship you might have with said party. Please present advertisements as advertisements and not as blog posts - we trust your blog. To me this is insulting.
- If you do want a content platform - please let users choose what content appears there directly (like the Q&A).

Note: none of this is about the company sponsoring or the article itself. I am not complaining about either in particular - this is about the concept.

Comment: Not to mention the first recommendation in the article about "JS best practices" was *literally* "don't write JS"...

Comment: Look at the first comment on the blog, and the reply to it. Apparently, SO pays for these blogs, even though it looks a whole lot like they get paid to publish them. It's a strange world...

Comment: Considering the ending paragraph and comments, it doesn't look like "sponsored content". Who do you think sponsored it? Binaris? The is no link to their product or products, is there?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get that vibe at all. Thought the article had some nice points in it. I'm going to try to use const more, for sure.

Comment: @yivi yes - and literally in the first paragraph

Comment: I don't see it that way. It links to the blog, not the the main site, and even on the blog it's not easy to navigate to their main product. Personally, I believe this is tilting at windmills. I don't think there are any giants here.

Comment: @yivi the "giants" are developers' trust in the platform, the fact the blog is used to push technical content under "stack overflow"'s name and reputaiion but said technical content is not under the same standards. That means that my peer-reviewed work on Stack Overflow gets associated with that marketing content. I honestly wouldn't mind if it was explicit.

Comment: @yivi let me make it clear. If there is no business relationship between the content provider (read sponsoring company) and Stack Overflow you have my word here that I will buy and eat a literal hat. If it had two small words "sponsored content" or a disclosure I would have been absolutely fine with it.

Comment: No problem Benjamin. I only mean it doesn't look that way to me, but I'm prepared to be wrong as well. No hat eating for me, thanks. :)

Comment: @yivi that's exactly the thing - the fact it doesn't obviously look that way is _exactly_ the issue I have with it :]

Comment: I'm not a big fan of these blog posts, but a one-sentence greeting with a link to the author's company website doesn't strike me as a huge deal. Sure, it's something we wouldn't tolerate in a post on the Q&A site, but I think you're making more of it than it's worth. I also think you're wrong about the author having paid to put this content on the blog. Both he and Ben Popper explicitly say the opposite is true in the comments on the blog post. Absent hard evidence otherwise, I assume they are not lying.

Comment: FWIW: _"We do pay contributors. Send us a pitch and if we think it’s worth publishing, we can discuss a fair fee  - Ben Popper"_

Comment: [Here is a nice selection of hats to choose from, Benjamin](https://bacontoday.com/2009/08/06/hats-made-of-meat/)...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your question is fair. Ryland doesn't pay us, we pay him, as we do all contributors who pitch us posts and ask for a fee in exchange.

As the intro at the top of Ryland's post mentioned, when we asked folks in the 2019 Dev Survey what they would like to see beyond Q&A, this kind of article was the [#1 request](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#community-_-opinions-on-new-content-types). That gives me confidence it's something our community wants us to at least experiment with, and the traffic and comments on this and other similar blogs back that up.

Comment: Thank you for for the clarification that is indeed a lot better. It would have still been significantly better to figure out a peer reviewed way to do this :) thank you for the response.

Comment: Can we at least do some non-JavaScript related stuff? I'd like to see some of this advice for C programming.

Comment: @JL2210 - since I joined we’ve published pieces on server migration, caching apps for multi-talent architecture, and how to research coding questions with a mindful attitude. We are open to pitches on pieces beyond JavaScript. If you have an idea for a piece on C programming, send it over to pitches@stackoverflow.com :)